# Are there any statistically sound ways to convert centrality scores in networks to rates?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, network-analysis

Right now, I'm finding the betweenness centrality of players on their respective hockey teams. Since some players may play 60 games while others may play 20 games, the players who play 60 games will almost always (understandably) have a higher betweenness centrality. However, I'm trying to think of a way to normalize the centrality for the number of games played, so that I can compare the influence of different players while accounting for how often they played.

I've tried dividing by Games Played, but this still underestimates the added effect of playing more games (check out the charts).

First chart is Games Played vs. Total (cumulative) Betweenness
[image]

Second chart is Games Played vs. Betweenness per Game Played (still a positive slope)
[image]

Ideally I want no relationship between games played and the normalized betweenness centrality, so that I can compare players regardless of how many games they played. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: I think instead of comparing the centralities of two players, lets say A and B, you should compare the centrality of A vs. the average centrality of players like A (i.e. same number of games) and the centrality of B vs. the average centrality of players like B. Those 2 comparisons will give you 2 new scores, one for A and one for B.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So -- just to make sure I'm clear on what you're saying -- you're suggesting that I only directly compare players who played a similar number of games, but then compare the rank (sort of) in their groups to each other?

Comment: Yes, hopefully my example below will help you understand, visualise and experiment a bit on how you can approach your dataset :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide any data so I'll use a built in dataset to help you.
The dataset is `mtcars` and imagine that `cyl` represents the number of games and `disp` represents your centrality scores.

You can see the relationship in this plot

```
library(tidyverse)

# plot cyl against disp
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, disp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]
Games played (i.e. `cyl`) is correlated with centrality scores (i.e. `disp`).

Then you can create new scores like this

```
# build the model
m = lm(disp~cyl, data = mtcars)

# use model to get estimated disp at a given cyl value
mtcars$pred_disp = predict(m, newdata = mtcars)

# calculate the difference
mtcars$diff = mtcars$disp - mtcars$pred_disp
```

And plot the new scores to see they are not correlated with games played

```
# plot cyl against diff
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, diff))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]
Games played (i.e. `cyl`) is not correlated with new centrality scores (i.e. `diff`).

Also, check dataset `mtcars` again focusing on the new variables that were created. The expected centrality score (i.e. `pred_disp`) is the same for each number of games value (i.e. `cyl`) as expected. And the new centrality scores (i.e. `diff`) are the old centrality scores minus the expected ones. A positive new score means that the player's centrality is higher than the expected centrality for that number of games. A negative new score means the opossite.

Note that you can do some further normalisation to variable `diff` (e.g. to take values from -1 to 1) if you want.

Comment: Great answer. Simple and intuitive.